# Appending to a list of dictionary values list won't work

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

So I have a dictionary and I want to get a list of all of its values plus one more.  So I do something like this

```
new_val = 'v3'
test = {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
l = test.values().append(new_val)
```

However when I do this `l = None`.  But if I use an intermediate

```
l = test.values()
l.append(new_val)
```

`l` contains what I want.  Why does the first method not work

Comment: Because `.append()` modifies the list in-place and returns `None`... so `l == None`... by assigning first, then appending, you update and still have reference to the original `l` to see the changes... you can use `l = test.values() + [new_val]` to create a *new* list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = test.values().append(new_val)
```

`l` is None because the return value of `.append()` (which is what you store in `l`) function is None.

```
l = test.values()
l.append(new_val)
```

This works because you first make a copy of `test.values()` and put it into `l`, and then append a new value to `l`

If you were to do

```
l = test.values()
x = l.append(new_val)
```

then `x` would also be `None`

Comment: Title was wrong, I meant to say appending to a list of dictionary values

Comment: I know it does, I was referencing the "This is also not the way to add entries to a dict".  I'm not trying to add entries to a dict

Comment: @sedavidw Oh, I'm sorry, removed that line :-)